# How can we encourage challenging questions?

Tags: discussion

When I saw the questions on the site homepage I found most of them are about seeking if a particular deed is permitted or not, and Some other questions have superstitious premises.

Of course, most of these questions receive down-votes. But these questions are still being asked. While in other religions these questions are fewer.

The first and most important question is that why are these kind of questions prevalence?

And how can we encourage challenging questions to be answered by Islam experts. For example, someone can challenge an Islamic law, or even a Quranic verse, or someone can ask about the reason for the existence of a particular law in Islam.